# Como pegar o valor de um input e colocar em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou tentando fazer um formulário de cadastro para um projeto e não conheço muito de JS, preciso tirar o valor do input apos a pessoa clicar no botão cadastrar e enviar para uma variável. Como faço isso? Estou usando angular também.

Exemplo de input:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="cpf"></label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Cpf" id="cpf" name="cpf" ngModel/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Cadastrar" />
</div>
```

Comment: veja isso: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitas maneiras de se pegar o valor de um `input` tanto com **JavaScript** puro quanto com **Angular** que utiliza **`Typescript`**, como está utilizando a segunda opção o mais desejável é utilizar as técnicas proporcionadas pelo Angular, como a 2 maneiras abaixo:

> Tomando como base este seu Html, a primeira maneira é utilizando a técnica de **two-way data binding**, juntamente com um `ngModel`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cpf"></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Cpf" id="cpf" name="cpf" [(ngModel)]="cpf" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Cadastrar" />
</div>
```

Na classe do seu componente TS:

```
export class SeuComponent  {
  public cpf: number;      // propriedade que liga o html ao ts e vice-versa

  cadastrar() {
    console.log(this.cpf)  // valor inserido no input
  }
}
```

Para saber mais sobre two-way data binding com Angular leia [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

---

> Outra maneira seria utilizar a técnica de **template variable** que utiliza um `#` como notação para uma variável da view juntamente com **@ViewChild()** que é responsável por transportar a variável do Hmtl para o Ts. Se utilizar a tipagem da variável como sendo do tipo **`ElementRef`** poderá ter tudo que precisar em relação aquele elemento Html inclusive o seu valor:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cpf"></label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Cpf" id="cpf" name="cpf" #cpf />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Cadastrar" />
</div>
```

Na classe do seu componente TS:

```
export class SeuComponent  {
  @ViewChild("cpf") cpf: ElementRef;    // propriedade que liga o html ao ts

  cadastrar() {
    console.log(this.cpf)  // valor inserido no input
  }
}
```

**Obs:** Dependendo da versão do Angular que está utilizando será necessário fazer assim `@ViewChild("cpf", {static: true}) cpf: ElementRef;`

**Obs:** Precisa importar o módulo de formulários do Angular no **app.module** para poder utilizar o `ngModel` nos formulários dos componentes

**Obs:** Apesar de não ter inserido na sua pergunta, precisa de um método no Ts para realizar o tratamento dos dados na ação do clique do botão como o cadastrar que inseri nos exemplos

**Obs:** Pode ver um exemplo com as duas maneiras diferentes implementadas [aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-inputs-8gfhy).

Answer (score -1):

No seu codigo está faltando definir um elemento **form** e explicar o que vai fazer quando o botão **submit** for clicado. Também falta a função que trata as informações.
Há várias maneiras de fazer isso, uma delas é com o código abaixo.

```js
function cadastrarDados(){
  var cpf = document.getElementById('dados').cpf.value;
  alert(cpf)
}
```

```html
<form id="dados" onsubmit="cadastrarDados()" >
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Cpf" name="cpf" id="cpf" ngModel/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Cadastrar" />
</div>
</form>
```